# I am getting an error which says "OperationFailure: $sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor"

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am having 173 documents and due to unknown reasons I am getting the below error. How do I fix this and what is the root cause?

```
OperationFailure: $sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor
```

I am using the below command with pymongo and using python 2.7

```
    db.Airlines2.aggregate([{'$sample': {'size': 8}}])
```

Comment: Did you try with a smaller sample size ?

Comment: What is your mongodb version ?

Comment: @JulienTASSIN its MongoDB server version: 3.6.5

Comment: @JulienTASSIN I changed the sample size to 2 and still getting that error but if I increase the sample size to 50 then it works. The issue is why it's not working for smaller sample size.

Comment: weird, this error should occur with too big sample size